# Gradle - How my own library can be used in the dependencies section

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing my own library for android. I want to allow other developers to use my library via the dependencies section in the gradle file. 
What should I do in order to enable this?

Thanks.

Comment: Build an AAR or a JAR (depending if your library needs resources) and publish it to Maven Central or JCenter.

Comment: To add to what @pdegand59 contributed, [click here](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/AAR), its googles explanation of the maven android plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy your library to Bintray and link your package to JCenter (that's the default repository configured when you create a new project with Android Studio).

[Here are some instructions on how to get started.](https://bintray.com/howbintrayworks#page1)

Please note that Bintray does not support SNAPSHOTs, but you can get [a free account in oss.jfrog.org](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26083425) if you have a Bintray package linked to JCenter.

[Here a project example](https://github.com/pieces029/velcro-parts) that has all the pieces in place (look for gradle scripts in /gradle directory)